# Tensor that depends on first-order derivatives of the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

The question is pretty straightforward. Just as all tensor fields depending on the metric's second derivative can be derived from the Riemann curvature tensor, is there any well-known tensor, such that tensor fields depending on the metric's **first** derivative can be derived from? One candidate for such a tensor could be the Christoffel symbol, however, it is not a tensor, so maybe some function of the Christoffel symbol could yield such a tensor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the framework of (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry, when the connection is the Levi–Civita connection, there is *no such tensor*. The proof of that could be found in Appendix II of the 1922 book *Space–Time–Matter* by H. Weyl  ([copy at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/spacetimematter00weyl_647/)).

We could consider a generic affine connection $Γ^\alpha{}_{\beta\gamma}$. For example, this happens in metric–affine theories of gravity when the connection is elevated to *independent variable*. Then this connection allows us to define two tensors, the *nonmetricity tensor*:
$$ Q_{αβγ}\equiv \stackrel{Γ}{\nabla}_αg_{βγ},$$
and *torsion tensor*:
$$
T^α{}_{βγ}\equiv Γ^α{}_{[βγ]}.
$$
For the Levi-Civita connection those tensors are identically zero.